# SQL - Doing an arithmetic expression reference to an alias (calculated in nested SELECT)

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL query, I need to do an alias based arithmetic on alias that is located within a nested select.

My query look like this:

```
    SELECT P.EMPLOYEE_NO, EE.BASIC_SALARY,
    (SELECT SUM (NEW_ACTIVITY_VALUE) 
        FROM 
            (SELECT 
                 (CASE WHEN P.ACTIVITY_TYPE = '0' THEN (P.ACTIVITY_VALUE * (-1))
                    ELSE P.ACTIVITY_VALUE
                  END) AS NEW_ACTIVITY_VALUE
                FROM V_EMPLOYEE_PAYACT P
                WHERE P.ACTIVITY_TYPE IN ('0','1') AND P.EMPLOYEE_NO = '00002789' AND
                    ((YEAR = 2014 AND MONTH <= 4)
                    OR
                    (YEAR > 2013 AND YEAR <2014)
                    OR
                    (YEAR = 2013 AND MONTH >= 5)) 
                    ) t
        ) AS SUM_ACTIVITY_VALUE,
    (SELECT NEW_BASIC_SALARY FROM
            (SELECT (EE.BASIC_SALARY- SUM_ACTIVITY_VALUE) AS NEW_BASIC_SALARY 
                FROM EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT EE
                ) AS X
FROM EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT EE
JOIN V_EMPLOYEE_PAYACT P
ON EE.EMPLOYEE_ID = P.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE P.EMPLOYEE_NO = '00002789'
GROUP BY P.EMPLOYEE_NO, EE.BASIC_SALARY
```

The only problem that I'm having now is at this part:

```
..(SELECT NEW_BASIC_SALARY FROM
            (SELECT (EE.BASIC_SALARY- SUM_ACTIVITY_VALUE) AS NEW_BASIC_SALARY 
                FROM EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT EE
                ) AS X...
```

If I deduct the above problematic part from the query, I got a result that looks like this:
EMP_NO |s  BASIC_SALARY|s SUM_ACTIVITY_VALUE|s 
1234-s-s-s|  2009-s-s-s-s-s-s-s| 100-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s|

What I need my result looks like is: 
EMP_NO |s  BASIC_SALARY|s SUM_ACTIVITY_VALUE|s NEW_BASIC_SALARY|s 
1234-s-s-s|  2009-s-s-s-s-s-s-s| 100-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s-s| 1909-s-s-s-s-s-s-s|

P/S: I am very sorry for my question formatting, kinda lost at how to format a table.

Comment: Are the  `s-s-s-s....` important for your result set? If so, where do they come from?

Comment: @HartCO that -s-s-s-s... i got from the 'advanced help' link given by stackoverflow for writing a question. They mentioned that "Create tables by separating columns with |s. The second row of a table must have at least three -s in each column." My result is actually without the '-s-s-s-s...' part.

Comment: Ah perfect, I figured that might have been the case, I don't know how to format tables on here either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be other flaws in your query, but if you're getting the values you want to subtract with your functioning query, than you can simply make that whole thing a subquery and do the subtraction outside of it, using the aliases:

```
SELECT *,BASIC_SALARY - SUM_ACTIVITY_VALUE as NEW_BASIC_SALARY
FROM (
 SELECT P.EMPLOYEE_NO
      , EE.BASIC_SALARY
      ,(SELECT SUM (NEW_ACTIVITY_VALUE) 
        FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN P.ACTIVITY_TYPE = '0' 
                            THEN (P.ACTIVITY_VALUE * (-1))
                            ELSE P.ACTIVITY_VALUE
                      END) AS NEW_ACTIVITY_VALUE
              FROM V_EMPLOYEE_PAYACT P
              WHERE P.ACTIVITY_TYPE IN ('0','1') 
                AND P.EMPLOYEE_NO = '00002789' 
                AND    ((YEAR = 2014 AND MONTH <= 4)
                    OR (YEAR > 2013 AND YEAR <2014)
                    OR (YEAR = 2013 AND MONTH >= 5)) 
              ) t
        ) AS SUM_ACTIVITY_VALUE
FROM EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYMENT EE
JOIN V_EMPLOYEE_PAYACT P
ON EE.EMPLOYEE_ID = P.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE P.EMPLOYEE_NO = '00002789'
GROUP BY P.EMPLOYEE_NO, EE.BASIC_SALARY
) sub
```

Comment: your solutions works like charm! I already got the result that I wanted. Thank you so much!